# How to monitor the collisions between multiple bodies

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, box2d, platformer

I'm making a 2D platformer with Box2D and LibGDX, shooter, and I'm implementing the logic for a snail in the game. The basic idea is that it walks across the ground leaving a sort of, slime trail, and when the snail is not colliding with slime, it should create more. I've set it up to where it will move across the ground creating slime objects, but I'm looking for a way to detect if the snail is colliding with any slime. I have this in my World contact listener:

begin contact:

```
    case Finals.SLITHERIKTER_BIT | Finals.SLIME_BIT:
        ((Slitherikter) ((fixtureA.getFilterData().categoryBits == 
        Finals.SLITHERIKTER_BIT) ? fixtureA.getUserData() : 
        fixtureB.getUserData())).isColidingWithSlime = true;
```

end contact:

```
    case Finals.SLITHERIKTER_BIT | Finals.SLIME_BIT:
        ((Slitherikter) ((fixtureA.getFilterData().categoryBits == 
        Finals.SLITHERIKTER_BIT) ? fixtureA.getUserData() : 
        fixtureB.getUserData())).isColidingWithSlime = false;
```

Depending on that variable:

```
if(!isColidingWithSlime && body.getLinearVelocity().y == 0) slime.add(new Slime(body.getPosition().add(0, -primaryFixture.getShape().getRadius()), color));
```

I understand why it doesn't work, but don't know what to do, Please help.

**EDIT** For clarification, I should specify, that if the snail is colliding with slime, I don't' want it to make more because this works pretty well, but I"m attempting to severely limit slime production to increase performance. I only want to create new slime if there's no collision at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with box2d, but my guess is that doing a lot of collision detection in favor of less "slime production" will not really boost your performance

Comment: What happens in the game is it constantly creates new slime objects because it doesn't know if any collisions are taking place, and because so many are created, after a bit, the game starts to lag.

Comment: Have you stepped through your game's frame loop in a debugger? Your slime generating code looks like it could be dropping slimes on top of themselves but not where the snail is. Seems like this may be leading to a whole lot of slime that your snail is vertically the `primaryFixture`'s radius away from.